# Curve Fitting piecewise function with a fixed parameter

Tags: python

I have a function as shown below

```py
   def PPM(x,a,b,c,d):  # d is the fixed parameter
       if x>d: 
          return 100/(1+((x-d)/c)**(-a))**b  
        else: return 0
```

the parameter d is fixed(calculated with lab data), and I need to curve fit to get all other parameters.

I am now using lmfit because I can easily fix parameter d.

```py
    from lmfit import minimize, Parameters 
    def residual(params, x, data): 
        d = params['d'] 
        a = params['a'] 
        b = params['b']
        c = params['c'] 
        if x>d: 
            PP = 100/(1+((x-d)/c)**(-a))**b 
        else: PP = 0
        return data-PP
```

but it shows **ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()**, I know it is related to vectorize the function with array but no idea how to do that in lmfit

I also modified the code above a little bit by doing

```py
    def residual(params, x, data): 
        d = params['d'] #the value of d is 0.078528, the fixed parameter
        a = params['a'] 
        b = params['b'] 
        c = params['c'] 
        PP = 100/(1+((x-d)/c)**(-a))**b 
        PP[np.where(d>x)] = 0 
     return data-PP


    params = Parameters()
    params.add('d', value=0.078528, vary=False)
    params.add('a', value=0.25, min=0, max=1)
    params.add('b', value=5, min=0.5, max=500)
    params.add('c', value=0.001, min=0.0001, max=1)
    out = minimize(residual, params, args=(x, data))
```

After modifying the code, there is no warning (error) after running but the fitted data looks terrible. It seems whatever the initial values I assigned, none have been changed. (I guess because if x is less than d, the function has no value)
By the way I use minimize from lmfit to leastsquare the residual
Is there a way to do it in python?
[Data and Fitting in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoOCf.png) the picture is what I expected
And the data

```py
    x = [6.2e-5, 1.2e-4, 2.5e-4, 5.0e-4, 1.0e-3, 2.0e-3, 4.2e-3, 8.8e-3, 2.0e-2, 
       4.6e-2, 1.1e-1, 2.6e-1, 6.0e-1]
    Data = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.056, 0.478, 3.725, 7.800]
```

Thanks!

Regards,

Steve

Comment: What is x and what is data when you call the function?  Can you provide context for the call.

Comment: Thanks Michael, x=[0.0000621, 0.0001242, 0.00024932, 0.00049772, 0.00100004, 0.00202676, 0.00417128,0.00878876, 0.01984992, 0.04636064, 0.10731156, 0.25733504, 0.60121724] data=[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.056443102,0.478543944,3.724743415,7.795926674] And in this case, the parameter d equals 0.07853

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to thank all of you who participated in the question.

I finally got what I would like by constraining the fixed value in a very small range.

I will show the code below.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
import pylab as pl


def PPM(x,a,b,c,d):  #  model
    """
    The model is pp=100/(1+((x-d)/c)**(-a))**b, d is the fixed parameter
    """
    pp = np.piecewise(x,[x <= d, x > d],[ 0,lambda x: 100/(1+((x-d)/c)**(-a))**b]) 
    return pp

x = [6.2e-5, 1.2e-4, 2.5e-4, 5.0e-4, 1.0e-3, 2.0e-3, 4.2e-3, 8.8e-3, 2.0e-2, 4.6e-2, 1.1e-1, 2.6e-1, 6.0e-1]
y0 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.056, 0.478, 3.725, 7.800] #x,yo are lab data
d = 0.071010176 #Calculated value for the fixed parameter
p1 = [1,1,0.5,d] # initial values for parameters
param_bounds = ([0, 0.1, 0.00001,0.99*d],[1, 18, 1, 1.01*d]) 
popt,pcov = optimize.curve_fit(PPM, x, y0, p0=p1,bounds=param_bounds)

#interpolation for plotting
x1 = np.linspace(x[0],x[-1],100)
y1 = [PPM(i,popt[0], popt[1], popt[2], popt[3]) for i in x1]


#plot
pl.semilogx(x, y0, "o", label=u"Lab Data")
pl.semilogx(x1, y1, label=u"Fitted Model")
pl.legend(loc="best")
pl.show
```

[image: The result from this code]

It looks good enough for me. If you have any advice or recommendations, please comment.

Thanks again!

Steve

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't have to be vectorized you can use list comprehension

```
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters
import numpy as np 

x=[0.0000621, 0.0001242, 0.00024932, 0.00049772, 0.00100004, 0.00202676, 0.00417128,0.00878876, 0.01984992, 0.04636064, 0.10731156, 0.25733504, 0.60121724] 
data=[ 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.056443102,0.478543944,3.724743415,7.795926674]

def residual(params, x, data): 
    d = params['d'] 
    a = params['a'] 
    b = params['b']
    c = params['c'] 
    PP = [100/(1+((x_-d)/c)**(-a))**b if x_>d else 0 for x_ in x]
    return np.array(data)-np.array(PP)
```

I have no idea what the values of a,b,c, and d should be so I made them up.

```
residual({'d':1,'a':2,'b':3,'c':4},x,data)
array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ,
       0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.0564431 ,
       0.47854394, 3.72474341, 7.79592667])
```

Comment: Now there is an error TypeError: zip argument #2 must support iteration Is it because I fixed parameter d? params.add('d', value=0.07853, vary=False)

Comment: I updated the answer cause I just saw that d wasn't in the array.

Comment: it still shows  ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().  I guess it is due to the vectorization.

Comment: try the updated one.  I'm not sure about the parameter values, but this works if you wrap the types in np.array() before doing the last subtraction.

Comment: From what @MichaelD said about wrapping in `np.array()`, is there a reason why `x` and `data` are not numpy arrays? I gave it a quick try and I can use comparison operators between numpy arrays and lists but it seems safer to just make everything an array.

Answer (score 1):

It is *always* better to include a full, minimal script showing what you actually did, and the actual results that you actually got, including the fit report.

Your question shows that you did fix the `np.any()` vs. `np.where()` issue. Great!

Your model still has

```
    PP = 100/(1+((x-d)/c)**(-a))**b
```

and the plot and question suggest that some values of `x` will be `< d`.  With `c` and `a` both positive real numbers

```
    ((x-d)/c)**(-a)
```

will have some values that are complex or give `nan`.   You then take 
`1 + ((x-d)/c)**(-a)` and raise that to the `b` power, with a starting value for `b` of 20!  That's pretty big and not very stable: `2.0**20` ~= 1 million, `2.5**20` ~= 100 million, and `3.0**20` ~= 3000 million.

I would suggest exploring your parameter space a little more.  For example, what do you get when you just evaluate your model with the starting values?  Is `b=20` reasonable for your data?   Note that the fit will start with your initial value, make very, very small changes to that to see what direction to move the parameter values.  If that very, very small change does not change the result, the fit does not know where to move to.

As a hint that you gave yourself: your plot of the data uses a log scale for the `x` axis.   I would also suggest using a log-scale for the y-axis,  and even **fitting in log-space**:  that is, treat `log(data)` as the data to be fit, and have the model compute the log of your PP function. Of course you wouldn't set `PP=0` where `x<d`, but you might set it to some very small value, perhaps like:

```
  pparg = (x-d)/c
  pparg[np.where(pparg<0)] = 1.e-30
  # log(pp) = np.log(100 * (1 + pparg**(-a)) **(-b)))
  logpp = np.log(100)  - b * np.log(1 + pparg**(-a))
  return (log(data) - logpp)
```

hope that helps....

Comment: I tried it and I got a warning ValueError: The input contains nan values from lmfit I believe.